# Which alcoholic drink can be best regarded as aphrodisiac?

Tags: health, drink, alcohol

Does alcohol help in sex? If so, which alcoholic drink is best act as aphrodisiac?

Comment: In some places getting someone drunk so you can get them to have sex is considered sexual assault.

Comment: The one that my girlfriend is drinking.

Answer (score 5):

**Which alcoholic drink can be best regarded as an aphrodisiac?**

**Well that will have to depend on the person!**

Alcohol seems to be able to work as an aphrodisiac. However, it is strongly recommended not to have more than a drink or two at most. More than that and any alcoholic drink may have a bad affect on one’s sex life.

> **Effects in females**
>
> It increases sexual desire — sort of
>
> A drink or two may boost arousal, but it’s not a sure bet.
>
> Drinking alcohol increases testosterone levels in females. This male sex hormone plays a role in sexual desire. It may be a factor in females reporting more sexual desire when drinking.
>
> There’s also an element of expectation. People often associate drinking with lowered inhibitions and feeling sexier and more confident. It’s kind of like a self-fulfilling prophecy: If you expect to get lucky when you’re drinking, you probably will.
>
> It can increase and decrease sexual arousal
>
> Some females may have more interest in sex when they’ve had a few drinks, but that doesn’t mean their bodies are going to be into it. - [Here’s What Happens When You Mix Booze with Sex](https://www.healthline.com/health/alcohol-and-sex#males)

Men should make sure not to over drink.

> **Effects in males**
>
> The effects of alcohol on males are a bit more straightforward.
>
> Getting hard might be difficult
>
> Yep, “whiskey dick” is a thing. And it’s not just whiskey that’s to blame. Any alcoholic beverage can do it. - [Here’s What Happens When You Mix Booze with Sex](https://www.healthline.com/health/alcohol-and-sex#males)

For the ladies, red wine causes the sex drive to be even more pronounced than with other drinks, at least [according to a group of Italian researchers](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19627470/) who discovered that the compounds in the wine actually enhance levels of sexual desire in the fairer sex. What the researchers uncovered was that the red wine specifically increased blood flow to women’s erogenous areas, which in turn led to increased levels of desire. The researchers were quick to point out, however, that after more than a drink or two the other effects of alcohol began to take hold, which led to a less pleasurable experience. Moderation, it seems, is key.

For those a little more adventurous, here are [nine aphrodisiac cocktails to spice up your night](https://vinepair.com/articles/cocktails-that-are-aphrodisiacs/):

- [Casino Royale](https://mixthatdrink.com/casino-royale/)
- [Chili Martini](https://whiteonricecouple.com/recipes/chili-martini-cocktail-recipes/#)
- [Ginseng Ginger Spritz](http://melbournecocktails.com/recipe-ginseng-ginger-spritz/)
- [The Chocolate Rye](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2014/02/chocolate-rye-whiskey-cocktail-valentines-day-drink-recipe-cacao-infusion.html)
- [Gin cocktail with honey and lemon cordial](https://simply-delicious-food.com/gin-cocktail-with-honey-and-lemon-cordial/)
- [Spiced Manhattan Cocktail](https://www.aspicyperspective.com/manhattan-cocktail-recipe/)
- [Gingered Peach Margarita](https://www.townandcountrymag.com/leisure/drinks/g13127599/ginger-beer-cocktails/)
- [Brandy Alexander](https://www.bustle.com/articles/110024-10-cinnamon-cocktails-you-need-to-feel-warm-and-fuzzy-this-fall)
- [Muscadet](https://vinepair.com/articles/seven-loire-valley-wines-you-must-be-drinking-this-fall/) wine with oysters

All said and done, there is no one liquor, liqueur, wine or any other alcoholic drink is the best aphrodisiac on the market. However, red wine ***seems*** best for the ladies.

To enhance the the mood, I would recommend some high end chocolates for the ladies.

Just keep in mind, that a drink or two seems to be the best. More than that can make the affects of the alcohol in one’s system can backfire.